# Key is already in use when trying to add SSH Key to Github

Tags: git, ssh, github

One of my developers has sent his SSH keys so I can add to Github.

I receive "Key is already in use" message.

How Can I fix that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He already has a GitHub account. Don't add the key, add his account (*Admin/Collaborators*).

Comment: How can I do that? It is for a particular project.

Comment: Settings > Manage Access > Invite a collaborator

Comment: @JamesMorrison I cant find this point. GitHub remove this point?

Comment: @MaxPattern It's now Settings > Collaborators >  Add people. You also must have the sufficient rights to invite people inside your repository.